# Amending Sharepoint List 2013 from MS Excel 2013

Tags: sharepoint-addin, custom-list

Is there any way to upload / connect the excel data with a SharePoint 2013 List. I have tried few add-on which changes the excel data in table and uploads to a SharePoint list however the issues is i am not able to update the same data again. This allows me to update data to new SharePoint list but not amend on the existing one. Also got one add-on which does the same job but limitations is ,we have to define the table range to 50000 ,this one works but SP will have blank rows, (ex if excel has 30 rows data and 49970 rows will be blank SP will have the 49970 blank rows) which doesn't looks good. Is there any way to amend the SP list with excel file. (If we do changes in Excel this should be updated in SP also)

Many Thanks

Appreciate your help.

Regards
Satish